# @nestjs/swagger install errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger

currently, When I install swagger on my nestjs project using yarn install I get the following error. Any ideas what may cause this?

> src/ledger/dtos/addOrdersByDate.dto.ts:2:10 - error TS2724: Module
> '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported member
> 'ApiModelProperty'. Did you mean 'ApiHideProperty'?
>
> 2 import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/decorators/api-hide-property.decorator.d.ts:1:25
> 1 export declare function ApiHideProperty(): PropertyDecorator;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'ApiHideProperty' is declared here.
>
> src/ledger/dtos/addRebatesCharges.dto.ts:1:10 - error TS2724: Module
> '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported member
> 'ApiModelProperty'. Did you mean 'ApiHideProperty'?
>
> 1 import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/decorators/api-hide-property.decorator.d.ts:1:25
> 1 export declare function ApiHideProperty(): PropertyDecorator;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'ApiHideProperty' is declared here.
>
> src/ledger/dtos/addReturns.dto.ts:2:10 - error TS2724: Module
> '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported member
> 'ApiModelProperty'. Did you mean 'ApiHideProperty'?
>
> 2 import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/decorators/api-hide-property.decorator.d.ts:1:25
> 1 export declare function ApiHideProperty(): PropertyDecorator;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'ApiHideProperty' is declared here.
>
> src/ledger/dtos/addSellers.dto.ts:2:10 - error TS2724: Module
> '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported member
> 'ApiModelProperty'. Did you mean 'ApiHideProperty'?
>
> 2 import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/decorators/api-hide-property.decorator.d.ts:1:25
> 1 export declare function ApiHideProperty(): PropertyDecorator;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'ApiHideProperty' is declared here.
>
> src/ledger/dtos/block.dto.ts:2:10 - error TS2724: Module
> '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported member
> 'ApiModelProperty'. Did you mean 'ApiHideProperty'?
>
> 2 import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/decorators/api-hide-property.decorator.d.ts:1:25
> 1 export declare function ApiHideProperty(): PropertyDecorator;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'ApiHideProperty' is declared here.
>
> src/ledger/dtos/transaction.dto.ts:1:10 - error TS2724: Module
> '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported member
> 'ApiModelProperty'. Did you mean 'ApiHideProperty'?
>
> 1 import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/decorators/api-hide-property.decorator.d.ts:1:25
> 1 export declare function ApiHideProperty(): PropertyDecorator;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'ApiHideProperty' is declared here.
>
> src/queue/controllers/queue.controller.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module
> '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported member
> 'ApiUseTags'.
>
> 2 import { ApiUseTags, ApiOperation, ApiResponse } from
> '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/queue/controllers/queue.controller.ts:10:19 - error TS2345:
> Argument of type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'Partial'.   Object literal may only specify
> known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type
> 'Partial'.
>
> 10   @ApiOperation({ title: 'List queues with message quantity' })
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/shared/controllers/configuration.controller.ts:2:24 - error
> TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no
> exported member 'ApiUseTags'.
>
> 2 import { ApiOperation, ApiUseTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/shared/controllers/configuration.controller.ts:12:19 - error
> TS2345: Argument of type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'Partial'.   Object literal may
> only specify known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type
> 'Partial'.
>
> 12   @ApiOperation({ title: 'Get configuration variables' })
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/shared/controllers/history.controller.ts:2:24 - error TS2305:
> Module '"../../../node_modules/@nestjs/swagger"' has no exported
> member 'ApiUseTags'.
>
> 2 import { ApiOperation, ApiUseTags } from '@nestjs/swagger';
> ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/shared/controllers/history.controller.ts:10:19 - error TS2345:
> Argument of type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'Partial'.   Object literal may only specify
> known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type
> 'Partial'.
>
> 10   @ApiOperation({ title: 'Get history for entity' })
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/shared/filters/http-exception.filter.ts:24:34 - error TS2339:
> Property 'error' does not exist on type 'string'.
>
> 24         error: exception.message.error,
> ~~~~~
>
> src/shared/filters/http-exception.filter.ts:25:36 - error TS2339:
> Property 'message' does not exist on type 'string'.
>
> 25         message: exception.message.message,
> ~~~~~~~
>
> src/shared/filters/http-exception.filter.ts:35:34 - error TS2339:
> Property 'error' does not exist on type 'string'.
>
> 35         error: exception.message.error,

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of breaking changes in 4.0 version of swagger package:
https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/migration-guide#breaking-changes

I guess at least part of the issues is coming from there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation from [@nestjs/swagger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/swagger)

under "*Migration from v3*" part, the following decorators have been changed/renamed:

- ...
- @ApiModelProperty is now @ApiProperty
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Change `ApiModelProperty` to `ApiProperty`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).